# how to show or find full path of file listed in the File->Open dialog?

Tags: front-end, files-and-directories, configuration

This question was posted 2 days ago at [community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/177946?p_p_auth=nj7Gderg). I had a good answer but it does not quit do what I wanted. Hence I am trying here to see if someone might know of some other solution.  Here is the question:

I tend to name some files, which are in different folders, with the same name. Say source.nb

But when going back to open a specific file from one folder, using File->Open dialog, it does not show the full path of the file. Even a right-click on the file name, or hovering the mouse over the name, has no pop-up menu to show the full path name. This makes it hard to know in which folder any of these files are in.  So I end up opening the wrong file many times. Here is a screen shot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I looked at options and did not see a way to change this. It might be there and I have overlooked it. I searched for "file" options. Using V 9.01 on windows.

Would any one know of a way to make it either display the full path name, or at least when hovering the mouse over the name, it will display the full path name in a small pop-up help display (which is the common way most applications handle this sort of thing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works on my system (v7, Windows 7):

```
Cases[
  NotebooksMenu /. Options[$FrontEnd],
  FrontEnd`FileName[{_, path__}, name_, ___] :> FileNameJoin @ {path, name},
  {3}
]
```

The first `_` in `{_, path__}` is to skip `$RootDirectory`; if you want to preserve `$RootDirectory` leave it out.

To create a palette with buttons to open these Notebooks you may use:

```
Cases[
  NotebooksMenu /. Options[$FrontEnd],
  FrontEnd`FileName[{_, path__}, name_, ___] :> FileNameJoin@{path, name},
  {3}
] // CreatePalette @ Column[Button[#, NotebookOpen@#] & /@ #] &;
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I use the output of the above? THe above just gives me a list of the file names with fullpath/ But what is next? I need to open a notebook. I am not familar with notebook commands. I just use the File->Open to open files.

Comment: @Nasser Sorry, I didn't realize that was part of the question.  Basically you can use `NotebookOpen` but I guess you want something more automated like a palette?

Comment: I see. So you mean I'd copy the file name from the `Cases` output, and paste into a `NotebokOpen` command? Ok. Will try that. Sure, a palette based method would be great and much easier to use, if possible. It would be useful for many others I assume. I hope this feature is added to V 10. But no problem if it is too much trouble. I'll try the copy/paste method for now. thanks.

Comment: @Nasser I added a palette generating function.  Please try it and let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: Nice. I tried it. Yes, much easier that way. Will use this from now on. I have many files with same name that I open all the time, and this helps allot. thanks.